# Javascript object to C# object does not correctly convert double

Tags: asp.net-mvc, implicit-conversion, javascript-objects

I'm trying to send a model created using javascript (because it is created manually by the user) to an MVC controller.

The model is quite complex and one class uses the `double?` type for a variable. It works fine with `int` numbers but when I use `"0.5"` the value is set to null.

What is the reason why double value fail and what can I do about it?

Some code:

```
var serie = {};

serie.Name = $(elem).children("#name").val();

serie.UnitMeasurement = $(elem).children("#unitMeasurement").val();

serie.ThresholdRed = $(elem).children("#redThreshold").val();

serie.ThresholdYellow = $(elem).children("#yellowThreshold").val();


public class Serie
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string UnitMeasurement { get; set; }
            public double? ThresholdRed { get; set; }
            public double? ThresholdYellow { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried to set it to "0,5"? (comma not dot), It might be a culture issue?

Comment: I think we are supposed to receive string values and then typecast them mannualy

Comment: It works now but does this culture issue depend on the server? How can I set what version I want?

Comment: You can set it in `web.config`, for example `<globalization uiCulture="en-GB" culture="en-GB" />` (in `<configuration><system.web>`)

Comment: @PankajDubey how do you manually typecast?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use your class like-

```
public class Serie
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string UnitMeasurement { get; set; }
    public string ThresholdRed { get; set; }
    public string ThresholdYellow { get; set; }
}
```

and then while using these varriables you can convert them like-

```
double? d = Convert.ToDouble(ThresholdRed);
```

or you can use `double.TryParse` like-

```
double d;
bool result = double.TryParse(str, out dbl); // `result` will be the status of tried Parsing (true or false)
```

### EDITED :(

In order to avoid any confusion with culture, encode your parameters before sending like-

```
var serie = {};
serie.Name = escape($(elem).children("#name").val());
serie.UnitMeasurement = escape($(elem).children("#unitMeasurement").val());
serie.ThresholdRed = escape($(elem).children("#redThreshold").val());
serie.ThresholdYellow = escape($(elem).children("#yellowThreshold").val());
```

While using them on server, decode them first-

```
double? d = Convert.ToDouble(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(ThresholdRed));
```

Comment: How would that possibly work. If the `DefaultModelBinder` cant bind it because of the culture, then `Convert.ToDouble()` wont either.

Comment: @StephenMuecke , that for your good catch.. Since he is not using DefaultModelBinder so I beleive he will have his culture setup.. but if not Then he should have asked it in the question.. But in any case he can use escape() function of jquery to encode the values.. and then back on server he can decode them with HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("{parameters}") then as well..